# Is there a way to set PostgreSQL Optimizer in Sqoop?

Tags: postgresql, etl, sqoop, data-ingestion

I am trying to run a sqoop job to ingest data from postgresql to hdfs and I am stuck on some point.

Sqoop adds " **AND (1=0)**" to the end of my "**WHERE**" statement to fetch metadata just before ingestion.

```
sqoop import 
--connect jdbc:postgresql://randomtexthere.com:5432/test 
--username user
-P 
--query 
"
SELECT * 
FROM table1 pr 
   INNER JOIN 
   table2 fr 
   ON pr.id = fr.id 
WHERE fr.another_id > 12345 AND fr.another_id < 123456 AND \$CONDITIONS
" 
--hcatalog-database test
--hcatalog-storage-stanza "STORED AS PARQUET" 
--hcatalog-table table1--split-by  id
```

Once above command is added, query never gets completed. (both in Sqoop and DBeaver)

However this query only works once I set SET OPTIMIZER = ON (in DBeaver)

```
SET OPTIMIZER = ON;

SELECT * 
FROM table1 pr 
   INNER JOIN 
   table2 fr 
   ON pr.id = fr.id 
WHERE fr.another_id > 12345 AND fr.another_id < 123456 AND (1=0);
```

I am looking for a solution to set optimizer parameter in my sqoop session.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: There is no parameter `optimizer`, so this `SET` will do nothing. Can you ascertain that the actual SQL command executed is what you think it is?

Comment: the Postgres optimizer should understand that `1 = 0` will return nothing. Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan of the slow query generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not jus a _simple_ explain) as formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

passing the optimizer hint in jdbc connection solves the issue.

```
--connect jdbc:postgresql://randomtexthere.com:5432/test?optimizer=true
```